# BigCommerce REST API URL to link cross-selling and up-selling

Tags: api, rest, url, bigcommerce

I am looking for bigcommerce rest api URL to link cross-selling and up-selling product. i use related_product array to send related product. but need cross-selling and up-selling REST API URL with cross-selling and up-selling category.

Does anyone know ? Please help me by sharing the same.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is out-of-the-box support for cross selling in BigCommerce. If you were looking to develop the functionality yourself you could use product (or product variant) metafields to do this potentially.

Comment: Thank You @jdswift, let me check Metafields